# MySQL IN clause EITHER value

Tags: mysql, in-clause

I have this query:

```
SELECT 1 IN (1,2)
```

Which returns 1 since 1 is inside (1,2).

What I want to do is check if either one of two values exists in the array. In an imaginary world:

```
SELECT (3,1) EITHER IN (1,2)
```

Something like this should return 1 since at least one value was found in the second array. Of course this query is incorrect. Is there a way to do this and avoid this:

```
SELECT (
   3 IN (1,2)
   OR
   1 IN (1,2)
)
```

Comment: you could create a temp table with int field and you could do select * from temp where id in (1, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an inner join for that

```
select a, b form T1
inner join T2 on (T1.a = T2.c or T1.b = T2.c)
```